# Dual VGA monitors (not mirrored) with Mac mini 2012

Tags: display, mac-mini, vga

Is it possible to do this some way? I need to work with to different monitors, not simply mirroring.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Mac mini should include both an HDMI connector, as well as a Thunderbolt connector.

If you are *actually* using VGA monitors with VGA connectors, you would simply need one HDMI -> VGA adaptor for one monitor, and one Thunderbolt -> VGA adaptor for the other.

If your monitors are newer, you might like out and one will already have an HDMI connector, so no adaptor is needed.

But the simple answer to your question is `YES`, you just need to buy the appropriate adaptors for the connections you have.